# Does it make sense creating a DB context instance inside an ASP controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have something like this

```
 public class FooController : ApiController
 {
        [HttpPost]
        public string CreateSomething(string action)
        {
           DBModelMgr m = new DBModelMgr(); 
           .......
           return ...;
        }
 }
```

Now DBModelMgr is a little resource intensive. Is there a way for me to have it instantiated once ? If I make it a member variable of the class it will still get created everytime CreateSomething method is called ? Correct ? Please correct me if I am wrong. Also I was thinking about making it a static variable but that would result in cross thread issues. Any suggestions on how I can handle this situation ?

Comment: I would suggest looking into a DI container.

Comment: @AliK How will a DI container help here? For each request a controller instance will be created, on each creation the DI will inject an instance of the context. You should not configure the context as singleton in the container. So you end up with the same

Comment: Yes it does, creating a new instance per a controller call is perfectly valid, different instances do not interfere and you correctly dispose them after used.

Comment: Can you give an example ? I am new to ASP so I am not fully aware of the life cycle of a controller

Comment: @MistyD For **each** http request a controller instance will be created. There is no reuse or recycling for any controller instance. Create, handle the request, garbage. Thats the life cycle of any controller

Comment: @SirRufo I understand. I wanted to know if there was a way for me to reuse this instance.Is there any other way i can do this other than creating a singleton class that returns this or a static class. /

Comment: I would never want to reuse a context not knowing the state of the context. Are there some unsaved entities left? I do not want to care about that and start every time with a fresh instance. You should examine your context why it is so resource intensive. From your code sample it seems you are **not** disposing the context instance ... but you should

Comment: my only concern is that the method will be called fairly often

Comment: Search for UnitOfWork design pattern to manage data access. There are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: As suggested before there are just some services you don't reuse and create new instances.  However, if you really want to reuse you need to look at singleton instance which in affect is static

Comment: Regarding example,s as mentioned do search for DI container for .net.  If you are using Asp.net Core there is one built in otherwise there are many others.

Comment: @MistyD That is called [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now DBModelMgr is a little resource intensive

What makes you think this?

Infact DBContexts are light-weight objects and **should** indeed be instantiated when required and disposed straight after.

> When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)